# C# How to assign default property value of static class

Tags: c#, properties

how can I assign default property value of static class in C#? I'm trying to do followings:

```
public class Unit
{
  public string Name;
  public double cConvertFromSI;
}

// want to do something like this:
public static Unit m  = (Name = "meter"; cConvertFromSI = 1;)
public static Unit mm = (Name = "millimeter"; cConvertFromSI = 1000;)
public static Unit in = (Name = "inch"; cConvertFromSI = 39.3701;)
```

Comment: The error is..? I'm not used to that syntax (is it from C#8 or made up?). Anyway, `public static Unit m = new Unit { Name = "meter", cConvertFromSI = 1 };` would be valid.

Comment: `public static Unit m { get; set; } = new Unit { Name = "meter", cConvertFromSI = 1 };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, do not use public fields, use properties with getters/setters, it will break the encapsulation. Second, you should instance an object of `Unit` and initialize the properties. See some examples:

```cs
public class Unit
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public double cConvertFromSI { get; set; }
}

public static Unit m  = new Unit() { Name = "meter", cConvertFromSI = 1 };
public static Unit mm = new Unit() { Name = "millimeter", cConvertFromSI = 1000 };
public static Unit in = new Unit() { Name = "inch", cConvertFromSI = 39.3701 };
```

Comment: Thanks so much, straight to the point, clear answer.

Comment: Remember to check it as the anwser to help other users!

Answer (score 3):

Why not implementing *constructor*? Why do we let create an *invalid* `Unit` instance (with `null` `name`) at all?

```
 public class Unit
 {
     public Unit(string name, double value)
     {
         if (name == null)
             throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
         if (value <= 0)
             throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value)); 

         Name = name;
         cConvertFromSI = value;
     }   

     // properties instead of fields
     public string Name {get; private set; }
     public double cConvertFromSI {get; private set; }
 }
```

And then

```
  public static Unit m = new Unit("meter", 1);
  public static Unit mm = new Unit("millimeter", 1000);
  public static Unit in = new Unit("inch", 39.3701);
```