# How can I get specific type of properties of a class?

Tags: c#

I have following class.

```
public class Unit
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public double cConvertFromSI { get; set; }
}

public class UnitList
{
  public Unit m  = new Unit() { Name = "meter", cConvertFromSI = 1 };
  public Unit mm = new Unit() { Name = "millimeter", cConvertFromSI = 1000 };
  public Unit in = new Unit() { Name = "inch", cConvertFromSI = 39.3701 };
}
```

And I want to get all 'Unit' from 'UnitList'.

```
// I want to do something like

UnitList MyUnitList = new UnitList();

foreach (Unit Unit in MyUnitList)
{
  // do something with each 'Unit'
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: why not use an actual List?

Comment: would you mind giving me an example?

Comment: Sounds like what you really wanted was a `List` or `Dictionary` holding those `Unit`s. You can still have properties accessing those values, but I wouldn't recommend using those for dynamic purposes.

Comment: You can find lots of info and examples of Lists online already - [start here](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+list)

Comment: C# 9/.NET 5 allows you to be particularly concise: `record Unit(string Name, double CConvertFromSI);` then `var myUnitList = new List<Unit> { new("meter", 1), new("millimeter", 1000), new("inch", 39.3701) }`.

Comment: I don't know how to define public List, therefore I will go with IEnumerable<Unit>

Comment: Huh? `List<Unit> units = new List<Unit>();`. And then add items to it. Any tutorial will show you the basics. Then you wouldn't need the UnitList class at all. (And from another point of view, the UnitList class is inflexible because every time you want to support a new unit type you have to alter the class. With a simple list, that isn't necessary, you just keep adding as many items as you want to the list)

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67891283/c-sharp-how-to-assign-default-property-value-of-static-class#comment120000122_67891283

Comment: got it, thank you for your help!

Comment: Me mechanical engineer having no idea of IT tech somehow able to put something together with C# without knowing what I am doing. It's worth knowing there are some people like me. (this was answer to deleted reply)

Comment: Absolutely there are people like you. We all were beginners at one time. All the more reason to be searching like mad and finding tutorials and books to teach you the fundamentals. Programming is also an engineering discipline. People think you can just "write some code" as if it's a throwaway thing, but actually to do it properly and create anything non-trivial requires some time invested in background study and understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the `IEnumerable<Unit>` interface.

```cs
    public class UnitList : IEnumerable<Unit>
    {
        public Unit m = new Unit() { Name = "meter", cConvertFromSI = 1 };
        public Unit mm = new Unit() { Name = "millimeter", cConvertFromSI = 1000 };
        public Unit in_ = new Unit() { Name = "inch", cConvertFromSI = 39.3701 };

        public IEnumerator<Unit> GetEnumerator()
        {
            yield return m;
            yield return mm;
            yield return in_;
            //...
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
          => GetEnumerator();
    }
```

That way you can iterate through a `UnitList` instance with foreach.

```cs
foreach ( Unit u in new UnitList() )
{
}
```

However, it would probably be more reasonable to just use a List or Array property instead.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have a good reason to not just use a `List<Unit>`, but this would solve getting the properties dynamically.

```
public class Unit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double cConvertFromSI { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name} {cConvertFromSI}";
    }
}

public class UnitList
{
    public Unit m { get; set; } = new Unit() {Name = "meter", cConvertFromSI = 1};
    public Unit mm { get; set; } = new Unit() {Name = "millimeter", cConvertFromSI = 1000};
    public Unit iN { get; set; } = new Unit() {Name = "inch", cConvertFromSI = 39.3701}; // in is a reserved keyword btw
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var unitList = new UnitList();

        var propertyInfos = typeof(UnitList).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(Unit));
        var units = propertyInfos.Select(propertyInfo => (Unit) propertyInfo.GetValue(unitList)).ToList();

        units.ForEach(u => { Console.WriteLine(u.ToString()); });
    }
}
```

Note that I added `{get; set;}` at the end of `UnitList` fields to make them properties.

If you want to keep them as fields then you would need to get the units like this

```
   var fields = typeof(UnitList).GetFields().Where(p => p.FieldType == typeof(Unit));
   var units = fields.Select(propertyInfo => (Unit) propertyInfo.GetValue(unitList)).ToList();
```